# What type of weapon should I use as an Unholy spec Death Knight?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm a first-time Death Knight and want to start playing with an Unholy spec, but I don't know what type of weapon I should use. Should I dual-wield two weapons, or use a single two-handed weapon for optimal DPS in PvP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, two-handed works best in pvp. Make sure you use the right glyphs, for example 'Anti-Magic Shell' and useful talents include 'On A Pale Horse' and 'Improved Unholy Presence'.

Personally, I've done better with a Frost spec in PvP but provided you use the right spell rotation, you should do fine with Unholy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you expand on why two-handed works better in pvp?

Comment: Well, I haven't played in a while but from my experience, some enchants for 2h weapons were better, for example. 2h can be a bit tricky when in a one-on-one situation. Especially against someone with a shield. Also, the calculations for 2h weapons with regard to attack speed or average dps can be greater than with 1h weapons.

Answer (score 0):

you will want to use a 2hander as unholy and 2h or dual wield as frost !

depending on the talent you pick in the frost tree and/or your hit rating

also u will want to use the rune of the fallen crusader on your 2h weapon

*btw unholy got badly nerfed in the last 2 patch so i would recoment going frost spec for dps even tho unholy is still viable frost should output more damage